# Finding where {$f_n(x)$} converges, where $f_n(x)=x(1-x^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'd appreciate a double check of my work and logic, and some help answering some questions.

1.) Finding where {$f_n(x)$} converges, $f_n(x)=x(1-x^n)$

Using the ratio test:

$$L=lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt {\frac {x-x^{n+1}}{{x-x^n}}}=\left|x\right|$$

Now with this test, $|x|\lt 1$ converges, and $|x|\gt 1$ diverges and if |x|=1 we need to do some further testing.

If I plug $x=\pm 1$ we get that $f_n$ converges on 1, but not -1.

Therefore the final answer would be on (-1,1].

**EDIT: the above answer using the ratio test seems to be incorrect. I've left it up so I could get some advice as to where I went wrong (besides mucking up the algebra on the ratio test!)**

2.) The next question is if the function converges uniformly on [0,1]. Checking point-wise convergence on [0,1] we see that $f_n(x)$ converges to 0. I'm not really sure how to test for uniform convergence, some help would be appreciated.

3.) Final question is if the convergence is "on average" on [0,1]. Finding a true translation rather than a direct translation proved difficult for this type of translation, but I believe we use the following test:

$$d_1(f_n,f)=\int_a^b|f_n-f|$$

What do we plug in for f to test it?

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: It does not make sense to apply the ratio test here

Comment: @FoobazJohn Yes it seems I might've made a mistake with my calculations. What test would fit then?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $0$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: 1) there is no such thing.
2) it doen't converge to $0$.

Comment: @JoeyZou how do you see that?

Comment: @RonaldB What does $x(1-x^n)$ converge to as $n\to\infty$ when $x=0.5$?

Comment: @ErickWong should be 0.5

Comment: @RonaldB Exactly, so it does not converge to $0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, which is what you claimed in (2).  Can you see what it does converge to?  (Note: the answer might look different for $(0,1)$ than it does for the endpoints.)